# unordered_map iteration order for the same key

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When looping over an `std::unordered_map`, STL makes no guarantees on which specific element order is considered.

My question is about the order of the elements with the same key, I tried it with different compilers and I always receive one after the other if they have same key (example below). I searched it but I couldn't find. Is it mentioned somewhere in standards or it is implementation dependent?

```
unordered_multimap<int, int> umap;

umap.insert({30, 9});
umap.insert({10, 1});
umap.insert({20, 5});
umap.insert({30, 8});
umap.insert({20, 4});
umap.insert({10, 2});

for (auto p : umap)
    cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;
```

outputs

```
30 8
30 9
20 4
20 5
10 1
10 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's mentioned in C++11 23.2.5/6:

> In containers that support equivalent keys, elements with equivalent keys are adjacent to each other in the iteration order of the container.

Comment: Added a question, the same key element is adjacent, but between them the sequence? Thanks

Comment: @RonTang: What do you mean? Elements with equivalent keys are adjacent to each other, so they form a sequence, as you observed.

Comment: I want to ask these same key's value sort by what rule, lesser ,greater,insert sequence or something else. Is this a UB. Thanks

Comment: @RonTang: There's no specified order, they're just grouped together.